# How to add a custom code analyzer to a project without nuget or VSIX?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, roslyn, analyzer

I want to write a custom code analyzer in Visual Studio 2015 for a C# ConsoleApplication. For this reason I don't want to create a seperate "Analyzer with Code Fix" project from template, because this requires to add this analyzer in my projects as nuget package.

[image]
Is it possible, to add a analyzer reference manually? I would like to reference the analyzer without nuget.

Comment: You can right click on 'Analyzers' and select an analyzer dll. Better question would be why you don't want to use nuget though.

Comment: @Jeroen Vannevel because why bother with nuget if it's only a custom local analyzer?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you add an analyzer as Nuget and check the content of your project, you'll see that only an `<Analyzer Include="..." />` item is added. You can do the same manually. Also, you can do this in the `.csproj.user` file as well, so you can also do it locally, and not commit this change to your SCM.

Comment: I've found in VS2017 at least that if you just add an <Analyzer/> tag to your project, you only get warnings when you build, not as you type. You seem to need to have the nuget package in the packages.config and the <Analyzer/> tag to get the warnings both when you're editing code and compiling.

Comment: I only get "<PackageReference Include="..."  What are you doing to get this? Its not working for me.

Comment: Beware that `<Analyzer Include="..." />` requires a path to an assembly, and won't work with csproj

Answer (score 10):

You can add analyzer via project reference with `OutputItemType` set to `Analyzer`:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\Analyzers\A1.csproj">
     <ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
     <OutputItemType>Analyzer</OutputItemType>
   </ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Or via element attributes:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Analyzers\A1.csproj" OutputItemType="Analyzer"
                      ReferenceOutputAssembly="false"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: works in VS2022